# Why does the order of dimensions change with boolean indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, boolean

When we have `M` of shape `(a, b, c)`, and an indexing array `v` that we use to index the last array, why does `M[i, :, v]` result in an array of shape `(d, b)` (with `d` the number of true values in `v`)?  As illustrated below:

```
In [409]: M = zeros((100, 20, 40))

In [410]: val = ones(shape=(40,), dtype="bool")

In [411]: M[0, :, :].shape
Out[411]: (20, 40)  # As expected

In [412]: M[0, :, val].shape
Out[412]: (40, 20)  # Huh?  Why (40, 20), not (20, 40)?

In [413]: M[:, :, val].shape
Out[413]: (100, 20, 40)  # s expected again
```

Why does `M[0, :, val]` have shape `(40, 20)` rather than `(20, 40)`?

Comment: The documentation for [Boolean Indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) covers your example - but I haven't figured it out what it means yet.

Comment: @BiRico Oops, indeed.  Corrected.

Comment: @wwii I read through that but I don't find an example where they use the last dimension rather than the first, for boolean indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the `boolean indexing` section of the docs
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

> Combining multiple Boolean indexing arrays or a Boolean with an integer indexing array can best be understood with the obj.nonzero() analogy.

```
ind = np.nonzero(val)[0]
# array([ 0,  1,  2, ...., 39], dtype=int32)
M[0, :, ind].shape   # (40,20)
```

So now we go to the section about combining advanced and basic indexing
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

This is a case of the form: `x[arr1, :, arr2]`

> in the first case, the dimensions resulting from the advanced indexing operation come first in the result array, and the subspace dimensions after that.

So the `0` and `ind` part produce a `(40,)` selection, while the `:` in the middle produces a `(20,)`.  By putting the `:` part last, the resulting dimension is `(40,20)`.  Basically it does this because there is an ambiguity in this indexing style, so it consistently opts to put the slice part at the end.

A way of selecting these values and maintain the shape you want (more or less) is to use `np.ix_` to generate a tuple of indices.

```
M[np.ix_([0],np.arange(20),ind)].shape # (1, 20, 40)
```

You can use `np.squeeze` to remove the initial `1` dimension.

This use of `ix_` is illustrated at the end of the 'purely index array indexing' section
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing

Comment: Right.  In my actual use case, I'm assigning values as well.  I see there are some caveats as to when the returning array is a copy and when it is a view, but it appears I do get a view when using `ix_`.

Comment: You don't get a view, but assignment `arr[foo] = b` always works. However, `arr[foo][bar] = b` is equivalent to `tmp = arr[foo]; tmp[bar] = b` which will do nothing if tmp is not a view on arr.